# Why my js script dont run in Magento 2 category products

Tags: magento2

I´already put my script in file requirejs-config.js and I think they are loading cause I can see reference in requirejs file loaded:

```
> var config = {
>     paths: {
>         'mageplaza/core/jquery/popup': 'Mageplaza_Core/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min',
>         **'mageplaza/core/color': 'Mageplaza_Core/js/color-picker-ewti'**,
>         'mageplaza/core/owl.carousel': 'Mageplaza_Core/js/owl.carousel.min',
>         'mageplaza/core/bootstrap': 'Mageplaza_Core/js/bootstrap.min',
>         mpIonRangeSlider: 'Mageplaza_Core/js/ion.rangeSlider.min',
>         touchPunch: 'Mageplaza_Core/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min',
>         mpDevbridgeAutocomplete: 'Mageplaza_Core/js/jquery.autocomplete.min'
>     },
>     shim: {
>         "mageplaza/core/jquery/popup": ["jquery"],
>         **"mageplaza/core/color": ["jquery"],**
>         "mageplaza/core/owl.carousel": ["jquery"],
>         "mageplaza/core/bootstrap": ["jquery"],
>         mpIonRangeSlider: ["jquery"],
>         mpDevbridgeAutocomplete: ["jquery"],
>         touchPunch: ['jquery', 'jquery/ui']
>     } };
```

My script is very simple, but they dont run and dont show any error:

```
define([], function () {
    alert("A simple Example module");

x = document.querySelectorAll('div[option-label]')
xArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(x)

xArray.map(x => {

//tudo minusculo
//cor = x.getAttribute('option-label').toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');

//primeira de cada Maiuscula
cor = x.getAttribute('option-label').normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');

cor=cor.split(' ').join('_')

x.classList.add(cor);

console.log(cor)

})

});
```

What ì´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this same problem, I went to the app/design/frontend/Smartwave/port/Magento_Catalog/templates/product directory and added to the list.phtml template file this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// made by www.ewti.com.br
    require([
        "jquery"
    ], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function($) { // after page ready, run!
            x = document.querySelectorAll('div[option-label]')
            xArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(x)
            xArray.map(x => {
                //tudo minusculo
                //cor = x.getAttribute('option-label').toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
                //primeira de cada Maiuscula
                cor = x.getAttribute('option-label').normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
                cor = cor.split(' ').join('_');
                x.classList.add(cor);

            })

        });

    });
</script>
```